# Timer in Custom Class only working in the init method Swift

Tags: swift4

I want to get a timer in my Custom Class but it is only working In the init method. So Ideally i would like to achieve:

```
class MyClass:NSObject{

    private var timer:Timer = Timer()

    //WORKING
    override init() {
    super.init()

    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (_) in
        print("\(self.logClassName): IN CLOSURE 1 \(self.recList.count)")

    })
    }
    //NOT WORKING
    func startTimer(){

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (_) in
        print("\(self.logClassName): IN CLOSURE 2 \(self.recList.count)")

        })
    }
}
```

The code shows that I initialise the Timer twice but it is just for explanation. I would like to use only the function startTimer()

Comment: Could you show the code to call `startTimer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the timer as optional

```
private var timer : Timer?
```

And there is a closing brace missing before `func startTimer()`.